# How can I save a video with a seperate audio data in vcl?

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player

I've got a video and separate audio data. I can open them both and watch them together in VLC but I would like to have only one video with the audio included, so save them together as one video with audio. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

1. Go to Media -> Open Multiple Files....
2. In the Open Media window, click Add....
3. In the Select one or multiple files window, select the desired video file. Click Open.
4. In the Open Media window, tick Show more options, then tick Play another media synchronously. Click Browse....
5. In the second Open Media window, click Add....
6. In the Select one or multiple files window, select the desired file that contains the audio which will be played on top of the video previously selected. (The file that contains the audio can be a video file.) Click Open.
7. In the second Open Media window, click Select.

*If the video already has audio, you need to select your second track. This is how:

When opening file, just tick [v] Show more options
Add  :audio-track=1 in Edit Options input field, for example:
Edit Options [ :file-caching=300 :audio-track=1]

(First track is 0 and second is 1)

8. In the first Open Media window, click the arrow near Play and click Convert.

Comment: Hey Thank you, Until the last step everything's fine but with clicking convert at the end it won't save the video with the selected audio, but only the video without sound... What could be the problem here...

Comment: When opening file, just tick [v] Show more options
Add  :audio-track=2 in Edit Options input field, for example:
Edit Options [ :file-caching=300 :audio-track=2]

Comment: Sorry, you pick one before the actual track so you would do :audio-track=1

Comment: What could be the reason that only the first 8 seconds get saved? :(

Comment: Is the video length longer than the audio? p.s. I'd appreciate if you'd do "answer accepted" if my answer helped.

Comment: No, it's actually the original audio of the video but somehow they're splitted. So they have the same length.

Comment: The only thing I can think is to try to give it a different track number. Try audio-track=0 or audio-track=2 - see how either of these work.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working :( thank you so much for your effort !

Comment: Maybe your original video has more than one track of audio so to get to the "audio" file - you might need to go even farther - audio-track=3, audio-track=4, audio-track=5 etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sowftware like Camtasia, it's very easy to use.you just have to drag the audio and vedio to the timeline and produce the vedio
here's the official download page : http://www.techsmith.fr/camtasia.html

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I have to do it with VLC since it's the universitie's computer and i can't install new programms on it... isn't there a way to do it with VLC?

Comment: i don't think so ..